# Magento2: How to login as customer frontend side?

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I want to log in as customer frontend side.

I have created a customer listing page. But when I click on customer login button customer login without login details.

My Magento v2.0.17

Comment: Can you share your screenshot?

Comment: In which page you want to add code?

Comment: I have created a custom block. Please check screenshot https://ibb.co/ek411V

Comment: Where is a login button?

Comment: I have not added button now. But I will add the login button to every customer.

Comment: When I click on the login button. The customer should be log in.

Comment: ok got your point. Wait I ll update my answer.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: try [magento 2 login as customer](https://www.mageants.com/login-as-customer-for-magento-2.html) module for your requirement you can test demo there if any question contact chat guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module with name **STech_Login** by following steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Login/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Login',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Login/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Login" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **routes.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Login/etc/frontend/routes.xml

with below content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="login" frontName="login">
            <module name="STech_Login" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **Lists.php** under

> app/code/STech/Login/Block/Customer/Lists.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Login\Block\Customer;

class Lists extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCustomers(){
        return $this->_customerFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**
Create **Index.php** under

> app/code/STech/Login/Controller/Index/Index.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Login\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Step 6:**
Create **Login.php** under

> app/code/STech/Login/Controller/Index/Login.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Login\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Login extends Action
{
    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customer = $this->_customer->load($id); 
        $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        if($customer->getGroupId() == YOUR_CONDITION){
            $this->_customerSession->setCustomerGroupData('ABC');
        }
        $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
    }

}
```

**Step 7:**
Create **login_index_index.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Login/view/frontend/layout/login_index_index.xml

with below content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Customer List</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="STech\Login\Block\Customer\Lists" name="customer_list" template="STech_Login::customers.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 8:**
Create **customers.phtml** under

> app/code/STech/Login/view/frontend/templates/customers.phtml

with below content:

```
<?php $customers = $block->getCustomers(); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($customers as $customer): ?>
    <li>Customer Name: <?php echo $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname(); ?> --- <a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('login/index/login', ['id' => $customer->getId()]) ?>" target="_blank">LogIn</a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Run setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy.

And test url with `http://example.com/login`

Comment: I will check and update you soon. Thanks!

Comment: The above one will work

Comment: Hi, It is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Tick the green tick mark near my answer if it's working for you so that it will help other developers in future.

Comment: Hi, I have one question. When I click on the login button then how to send custom variable session after login?

Comment: You can set custom variable to session in Login controller execute function which is execute when you click on login button.

Comment: Ok, Can you edit your post with the custom variable session?

Comment: What is the variable you want to set? Give me few minutes I ll update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84898/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-sukumar-gorai).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like this.

https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-login-as-customer

Comment: It is helpful for the backend side. I need the frontend. Thanks.

Comment: you can customize the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :**

```
First you need to inject \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer and \Magento\Customer\Model\Session classes in your constructor

protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

public function _construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    ...
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

Then,  add this code in your function :
$email = "test@m2s.com";
$customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail($email); 
$this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

---

**Method 2 :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerID = 2;
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerID);
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

**For better coding standard, Don't use object manager directly.**

Answer (score 0):

May this help

- [yoursite_url]/customer/account/logout
- [yoursite_url]/customer/account/login/

change [yoursite_url] with your magento installation root.